# Caching (Cache) directory in RHEL / CentOS

Tags: caching, centos, ram, rhel

How to cache a particular directory in RHEL / CentOS ? Suppose I have a directory which contains 10 GB data and I've 48 GB of RAM. How to cache all these data inside the directory(only this specific directory) to my memory for a specific amount of time or indefinitely ?

Answer (score -1):

There's a standard memory device on each Linux system  /dev/shm.

When you run the mount command you will see:

tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)

Generally it's about half the size of the system's memory  so if you have 48GB of RAM, its size will be about 24GB. ( you can check this by running df -h )

You can use /dev/shm as if it was a normal hard drive, for example, you can copy a file to it:

cp -r "YOUR DIRECTORY" /dev/shm/

that will do the tirck

Comment: This should not be necesary. Why is it?